# Asynchronously loading css via script vs linking css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asynchronous

I have a website where I use fontawesome. I used to include fontawesome via

```
<link rel="stylesheet" src="example.com/fa.css">
```

Now I use the following script to asynchronously load the css:

```
// Asynchronously load non-critical css
function loadCSS(e, t, n) {
    "use strict";
    var i = window.document.createElement("link");
    var o = t || window.document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    i.rel = "stylesheet";
    i.href = e;
    i.media = "only x";
    o.parentNode.insertBefore(i, o);
    setTimeout(function() {
        i.media = n || "all"
    })
}

// load css file async
loadCSS("//example.com/fa.min.css");
```

But I am in doubt that this `script` increases complete page load time than the `link`.
So can anyone tell which one will me more faster and efficient?

Comment: The page will probably load faster since the script is probably shorter than the `fa.min.css`. Though the css will not be available until it has been loaded i think.

Comment: Thank you @Arg0n I am thinking the same. But still in doubt. Some more views from more people may help I think.